# Using count and union together in SQL query

Tags: sql, union, union-all

I have two SQL queries

```
select count ( distinct w.processno ) AS "Number of Processes", y.userid from upmfolder f, upmperson p, w2process w, w2processcheck y where f.personid = p.personid and f.folderid = w.keynumb and w.Processno = y.processid and w.keyobject ='UPMFolder' group by 2
```

and another similar one is :

```
select count ( distinct w.processno ) AS "Number of Processes", y.userid from upmfolder f, upmperson p, w2process w, w2processcheck y where f.personid = p.personid and f.payrollmemberid = w.keynumb and w.keyobject = 'UPMPayrollmember' and w.Processno = y.processid group by 2
```

How would I combine the two into just one query? So the count and group would still function correctly. I tried with `union all`, however this didn't work. What do I need to do?

Comment: doesn't it depend on what you wish to count as a whole? I mean, how would you want to treat processes that satisfy both queries? Counted once? twice?

Comment: I'm only counting once

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.  For a `count(distinct)` you need to supply a NULL value:

```
select y.userid,
       count(distinct case when w.keyobject ='UPMFolder' then w.processno end) as NumFolder, 
       count(distinct case when w.keyobject ='UPMPayrollMember' then w.processno end) as NumPayrollMember
from upmfolder f, upmperson p, w2process w, w2processcheck y
where f.personid = p.personid and
      f.folderid = w.keynumb and
      w.Processno = y.processid
group by y.userid
```

Note:  You should also learn modern `join` syntax.  I haven't changed the query, but the join conditions should really be in an `on` clause rather than in the `where` clause.